# Change mandatory field to optional

Tags: php, forms

My PHP knowledge is limited and I need to change a field in a form - from mandatory to optional - `EMAIL FIELD`.

Here is the function code:

```
function apostherapy_leads_form($options) {

$defaults = array(
'id'           => 'frmLead' . rand(10, 99),
'title'        => '',
'msg_success'  => 'תודה רבה',
'msg_failure'  => 'אירעה שגיאה. נא לנסות שוב. תודה',
'url'          => 'http://leads.apostherapy.co.il/api/receiver.asp',
'campaign'     => '',
'source'       => get_bloginfo('name', 'display'),
'url_success'  => '',
'url_failure'  => '',
'placeholders' => false,
'with_join'    => false,
'ajax'         => true,
'label_name'   => 'שם מלא',
'label_phone'  => 'טלפון',
'label_email'  => 'אימייל',
'label_join'   => 'הנני מאשר קבלת חומר פרסומי מאפוסתרפיה',
'label_send'   => 'שלח',
);

$defaults['name'] = $defaults['id'];
$options = !empty( $options ) ? array_merge( $defaults, $options ) : $defaults;
ob_start();

if (!empty($options['title'])): ?><h2><?= $options['title'] ?></h2><?php endif; ?>
<div class="leads<?php if ($options['ajax']): ?> ajax<?php endif; ?>">
<p class="success"><?= $options['msg_success'] ?></p>
<p class="failure"><?= $options['msg_failure'] ?></p>
<form id="<?= $options['id'] ?>" name="<?= $options['name'] ?>" action="<?= $options['url'] ?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="nCampaignID" name="nCampaignID" value="<?= $options['campaign'] ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="sSource" name="sSource" value="<?= $options['source'] ?>">
  <?php if (!empty($options['url_success'])): ?><input type="hidden" id="sSuccessRedirURL" name="sSuccessRedirURL" value="<?= $options['url_success'] ?>"><?php endif; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($options['url_failure'])): ?><input type="hidden" id="sFailedRedirURL" name="sFailedRedirURL" value="<?= $options['url_failure'] ?>"><?php endif; ?>

  <p>
    <?php if (!$options['placeholders']): ?><label for="sFullName"><?= $options['label_name'] ?></label><?php endif; ?>

    <input name="sFullName"<?php if (!$options['placeholders']): ?> id="sFullName"<?php endif; ?> type="text" value="" maxlength="30"<?php if ($options['placeholders']): ?> placeholder="<?= $options['label_name'] ?><?php endif; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <?php if (!$options['placeholders']): ?><label for="sPhone"><?= $options['label_phone'] ?></label><?php endif; ?>
    <input name="sPhone"<?php if (!$options['placeholders']): ?> id="sPhone"<?php endif; ?> type="tel" value="" maxlength="11"<?php if ($options['placeholders']): ?> placeholder="<?= $options['label_phone'] ?><?php endif; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <?php if (!$options['placeholders']): ?><label for="sEmail"><?= $options['label_email'] ?></label><?php endif; ?>

    <input name="sEmail"<?php if (!$options['placeholders']): ?> id="sEmail"<?php endif; ?> type="email" value="" maxlength="50"<?php if ($options['placeholders']): ?> placeholder="<?= $options['label_email'] ?><?php endif; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" class="clsButton" value="<?= $options['label_send'] ?>">
    <?php if ($options['with_join']): ?><label for="sComments" class="join-newsletter"><input type="checkbox"checked='checked' name="sComments"<?php if (!$options['placeholders']): ?> id="sComments"<?php endif; ?> value="הירשם לניוזלטר קבל עדכונים למייל"><span><?= $options['label_join'] ?></span></label><?php endif; ?>
  </p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'leads_form', 'apostherapy_leads_form' );
```

As I said - I just want to change the EMAIL field from mandatory to optional

How can I change it ?

Thanks

Comment: How this field is mandatory?

Comment: please also include the code which is processing the html elements. then we can make it optional. Let us see the code

Comment: Hi - I updated my question to include the complete function - I hope it will help you - Thanks

Comment: If you are going to post that much code its a good idea to run it though a beautifier first.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that it is mandatory because of the PHP code that is checking the submitted data, as nothing in this HTML code is defining it as a mandatory field.

So you need to show us the PHP that deals with it.

It's probably something like:

```
if(!isset($_POST['sEmail'])){echo "error";}
```

You'll just remove the relevant part.

Comment: How are you so sure about it?

Comment: I never said that I was sure about it, I said "I'm assuming". I need to see what is causing this field to be mandatory because it's not this code, right?

Comment: You shall not assume here.

Comment: I absolutely shall assume here, as he's not giving me enough information to work with. I think my assumption is more than fair, and you seem to consistently be questioning every answer I make. Can you please just leave me to it?

Comment: I agree that you can give your assumption, but maybe the best place to give it is comments' section, not answers'. :)

Comment: Ah, okay. I posted here since I gave a possible solution but I guess it's not really an answer XD - Thanks, will use comments from now on unless I have a definitive answer.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for you interest, I just updated my questions with the full function - I hope it will provide the info you need - Thanks

Comment: Hi Yaron, sorry, I think you misunderstood me. I need the code that deals with the form data after it was sent, not the code that writes the form. It's sent to ['url'] which is: http://leads.apostherapy.co.il/api/receiver.asp - The code that deals with it will be on this page. It's a .asp page and I've never done any ASP but I'll probably be able to figure it out. On that page, it will do something with the form data, and that's the code that I need to see in order to solve this. :)